# Can the kidneys utilize ketone bodies for energy?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, kidney, renal-physiology

Ketone bodies are water-soluble and should pose no problem to the kidneys because of solubility. If the kidneys are able to utilize ketone bodies for energy, then they must express the enzyme 3-ketoacyl-CoA transferase, correct?

**Do the kidneys express the enzyme 3-ketoacyl-CoA transferase?**

**Can kidneys use ketone bodies as fuel?**

Comment: This article's abstract says that 3-ketoacid-CoA transferase was found in the kidney: http://www.nature.com/pr/journal/v42/n4/abs/pr19972518a.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexandria's answer:

This article's abstract says that 3-ketoacid-CoA transferase was found in the kidney: nature.com/pr/journal/v42/n4/abs/pr19972518a.html